# Can I pass objects or values from one rake task to another?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a series of rake tasks that seeds several objects and perform certain actions based on data in a spreadsheet.  The very first task in the series, though, validates the spreadsheet and checks that all the data is in the correct form.  I have a task that runs all the tasks in the series one by one, but I want to alter it so that it will abort all tasks after the sheet validation if the sheet is invalid, how can I do this?

I essentially want to have some form of communication between the sheet validation task and the overarching task running all tasks.  What's the ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abort the rake execution by calling `abort` in any task.
By using dependencies the following tasks never get executed if any of the preceding ones fails.

```
task :validate do
  abort "validation failed"
end

task :second do
  puts "never executed"
end

task :default =>  [:validate, :second]
```

**EDIT**

Concerning the arguments, i suggest using a class that keeps the state so you don't have to pass arguments around:

```
class Spreadsheet
  def initialize(args)
    # ...
  end

  def validate
    false
  end
end

task :init do
  @spreadsheet = Spreadsheet.new("something")
end

task :first do
  unless @spreadsheet.validate
    abort "validation failed"
  end
end

task :second do
  puts "never executed"
end

task :default =>  [:init, :first, :second]
```

Comment: Dependencies != argument passing.

Comment: No, but you're asking how to abort if the validation fails, aren't you? Do you really need to pass arguments around? You could for instance keep a stateful object that does all the logic for you.

Comment: *I’m* not asking anything.